# Self-removal button works only after the second click. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have made a button that should self-remove, but it gives me an unexpected result: on the first click it does everything but not self-remove, on the second click it does everything including self-remove. I would like to know explanation of that and how to make it self-remove on the first click.
*As the self-remove i mean `MainForm.Controls.Remove(StartButton);`*

```
StartButton.Location = new Point(132, 35);
StartButton.Name = "StartButton";
StartButton.Size = new Size(85, 37);
StartButton.Text = "Start";
StartButton.Click += new EventHandler(StartButton_Click);
void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm.Controls.Remove(StartButton);
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
}
```

Console output:

```
Clicked
Clicked
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem in a clean form. Consider posting a [MCVE]. At the moment it's not cleat what `MainForm` or `StartButton` are pointing to.

Comment: Must be something else in your code that's preventing the form from refreshing. What else is in your form? Any other event handlers or logic that could break it? Can you reproduce in the case of one button on a blank form?

Comment: @Baldrick Yes, It works on a blank form, then thats something else in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were in my code. There were a void that creates a button, and it were called 2 times by a mistake. So there were two buttons.

```
CreateButton()
CreateButton()
Void CreateButton()
{
        StartButton.Location = new Point(132, 35);
        StartButton.Name = "StartButton";
        StartButton.Size = new Size(85, 37);
        StartButton.Text = "Start";
        StartButton.Click += new EventHandler(StartButton_Click);
        void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainForm.Controls.Remove(StartButton);
            Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
        }
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Still, you should Dispose, not remove... :)